# How to get all text of a HTML document (except script/style/noscript tags) using Kuchiki?

Tags: html, rust, html5ever, kuchiki

I'm trying to get all the text on a HTML page, except for non-visible text (example: I don't want text inside script/style/noscript tags).

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```rust
let parser = kuchiki::parse_html().one(content);
for child in parser.inclusive_descendants() {
    if let Some(el) = child.as_element() {
        let tag_name = &el.name.local;
        if tag_name == "script" || tag_name == "style" || tag_name == "noscript" {
            child.detach();
        }
    }
}
let text = parser.text_contents();
println!("{}", text);
```

The idea is that the 1st pass will remove any `script`, `style`, or `noscript` tags. And then I can call `text_contents` to get the visible text.

However, it seems like `text_contents` is still returning inline Javascript.

Am I mis-understanding the Kuchiki/html5ever API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inclusive_descendants()` iterator doesn't seem to like iterating over nodes *and* detaching them.

Given the following:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
kuchiki = "0.8.1"
```

**main.rs**

```rust
use kuchiki::traits::TendrilSink;

let content = "\
    <html>\
    <head></head>\
    <body>\
        <div>div </div>\
        <script type='text/javascript'>script </script>\
        <noscript>noscript </noscript>\
        <span>span</span>\
    </body>\
    </html>";

let parser = kuchiki::parse_html().one(content);

for child in parser.inclusive_descendants() {
    if let Some(el) = child.as_element() {
        println!("{}", el.name.local);
    }
}

// println!("{}", parser.text_contents());
```

We *do* get all nodes:

```
html
head
body
div
script
noscript
span
```

When using `text_contents()` after iterating over them *and* detaching them like above, the iterator seems to lose track after the first detached node:

```
div noscript span
```

It doesn't seem to depend on the *type* of tag either, as switching the order of the `<noscript>` and `<script>` tag around gives us:

```
div script span
```

I found that detaching the nodes *after* collecting them first does seem to work:

```rust
parser
    .inclusive_descendants()
    .filter(|node| {
        node.as_element().map_or(false, |e| {
            matches!(e.name.local.as_ref(), "script" | "style" | "noscript")
        })
    })
    .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    .iter()
    .for_each(|node| node.detach());

println!("{}", parser.text_contents());
```

```
div span
```